# Does the Valkyrie have to win to earn extra glory?

Tags: blood-rage

The Valkyrie monster upgrade card states, "Gain 2 glory per enemy figure destroyed in battle with this monster."

It does not say "per enemy figure destroyed in **a** battle with this monster."

It does not say "per enemy figure destroyed in battle **by** this monster."

I believed it to mean "destroyed with this monster", meaning that the Valkyrie has to be on the winning side of the battle to claim the glory.

It was argued that it meant in any battle involving the Valkyrie, all casualties gave the player 2 glory, even if the Valkyrie lost and was sent to Valhalla. In combination with Frigga's Domain, the Valkyrie can become incredibly powerful. Returning from the dead (for 1 rage!), your Valkyrie could lose in another battle, claiming 2 glory per destroyed figure.

How does the Valkyrie monster upgrade for Blood Rage work?

Comment: Never assume that you're playing Blood Rage wrong just because something seems "broken".  The entire game is based around so many "broken" combos existing that they balance each other out.

Comment: Also, dropping the Valkyrie repeatedly is unlikely to earn you many extra points, since a big battle with lots of enemies dying makes it less likely that your opponents will have the figures for another big battle with lots of enemies dying. If it's just the Valkyrie dying, you're just wasting rage and giving points to the opponent.

Answer (score 5):

**The player controlling Valkyrie will gain points for all destroyed figures in that battle, even if it is destroyed.**

From the [official FAQ on CMON's site](https://cmon-files.s3.amazonaws.com/pdf/assets_item/resource/31/Blood_Rage_FAQ_1.1.pdf):

> **Q. Does the Valkyrie (*gain 2 Glory per enemy figure destroyed*) get glory for destroyed enemy units if she is destroyed in the course of a battle?**
>
> A. Yes, with the Valkyrie you get Glory for all figures destroyed from the Call to Battle to the battle’s Resolution, even if she is destroyed at any point during the battle.